# Parsing files on a remote computer

Tags: parsing, remote-access, mount

I have two systems. Now I have some log files on one system that are being generated periodically ( like every hour ). Now I want to parse those files from another system.
One way is to copy the files and then parse them. But this will consume a lot of bandwidth at a time(while copying) and if I parse the files on original system then it will increase the CPU utilization of that which I dont want. 
Can somebody suggest me some way to achieve this as optimally as possible.
In simple words, what I want is: I have a system A and from A, I want to parse the files located on Remote System B so that I dont have much load on system B ( dont bother about the load on system A ) and also the load on network is optimized.

Comment: I would just use rsync. What type of systems are you on and what kind of load?

Comment: If you want to run the parser on A, you have to get the data over there somehow.

Comment: These systems are the production servers where the server runs. I dont want to put load on System B's CPU as I have a different system A for this.

Answer (score 0):

As tjameson suggested, you should you rsync. I would like to add the use of the `-z` flag, which compress the files before transporting, then uncompress them at the destination. This flag helps minimizing the amount of data transferring. For example, the following command (on system B) sync the files from systemA, directory logs/ over:

```
rsync -az systemA:logs .
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But i think rsync will maintain a replica of the remote files which I don't want. I just to copy or somehow access the remote files for parsing and get the result. Can I use mount for this work ???

Comment: I don't know how mount works. If you just want to copy, use the `scp` command with the `-C` flag for compression.